# selected list box value show togethar

Tags: vb.net, listboxitem

I have a list box ...my list box has multiple item..if i select multiple item i want to show multiple item the same time in message box ..my code like this:

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
Dim locid As Integer
 If cnt > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To cnt - 1
            Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
            locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
            list.Add(locid)
        Next

        For Each num In list
            MessageBox.Show("LocID:" & num)

        Next
```

now each time i am getting each value in message box..i want to get all value at same time..how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the list elements with `String.Join()` method instead of using a loop.

An example:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer) From {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("LocID: {0}", String.Join(", ", list)), _
                Nothing, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Comment: i am getting out put..if i select two item from my list box i am able to press ok button in the messge box two time..

Comment: always i want to exit messagebox if i press ok button

Comment: i removed foreach..now i got proper answer

Comment: that's it I've tried to tell you that you need to replace (delete) the loop to a String.Join method.

Comment: i have one more doubt..can i ask?

Comment: of course ask, we are here to help. but if this question is not related with the original question then maybe you will better consider to create a new question where people could answer you.